# Combining Vuforia Ground Plane and Model Target in Unity3D

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm working on a iOS AR app which scans a model target and shows up the augmented content. However, I want the AR model to be anchored in world coordinates, like in ARKit.

I have implemented the code mentioned here: https://gist.github.com/vad710/015629ca8d56b4a016e072cd0c2dd18c, I've modified it for Model Targets instead of Image Target and I'm able to world anchor the models but the orientation is weird. I'm lost and I don't understand why the model is not aligned properly.

If any of you have any insights on how to identify a model target and keep the AR models anchored in the world, please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: i'm very curious about this too

Comment: I've been surfing through forums, and I am trying stuff with ARFoundation, as well as using Vuforia Fusion for ARKit support. But the documentation for these is so limited that I don't even know where to start..